# Difference between size_t and mwSize when compiling C MEX-files for Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, types, 32bit-64bit, mex

I am currently working on porting some C MEX-files for 32-bit Matlab to 64-bit Matlab.

While doing so, I have encountered two types, one coming from the Matlab people, and one which is C standard.

This is what the Matlab documentation is saying about `mwSize`:

> `mwSize` (C and Fortran)
>
> Type for size values
>
> Description
>
> `mwSize` is a type that represents size values, such as array dimensions. Use this function for cross-platform flexibility. By default, `mwSize` is equivalent to `int` in C. When using the `mex -largeArrayDims` switch, `mwSize` is equivalent to `size_t` in C. In Fortran, `mwSize` is similarly equivalent to `INTEGER*4` or `INTEGER*8`, based on platform and compilation flags.

This is what Wikipedia is saying about `size_t`:

> `size_t` is an unsigned data type defined by several C/C++ standards (e.g., the C99 ISO/IEC 9899 standard) that is defined in `stddef.h`.[1] It can be further imported by inclusion of `stdlib.h` as this file internally sub includes `stddef.h`[2].
>
> This type is used to represent the size of an object. Library functions that take or return sizes expect them to be of this type or have the return type of `size_t`. Further, the most frequently used compiler-based operator `sizeof` should evaluate to a value that is compatible with `size_t`.
>
> The actual type of `size_t` is platform-dependent; a common mistake is to assume `size_t` is the same as `unsigned int`, which can lead to programming errors,[3][4] when moving from 32 to 64-bit architecture, for example.

As far as I can see, these types are actually the same. My questions are:

1. Are they?
2. If they are, which one would be considered better programming taste to use? Ideally we would like our code to be compatible with future Matlab releases as well. I am guessing that the answer is `mwSize`, but I am not sure.

Edit: I should add that the Matlab people are using both. For example:

```
size_t mxGetN(const mxArray *pm);
```

is a function that is retrieving the number of columns of an mxArray. However, when one creates a matrix, one uses,

```
mxArray *mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mwSize m, mwSize n, mxComplexity ComplexFlag);
```

where the input evidently should be mwSize.

Comment: Hmmm ... as a basic check just make sure they have the same size: `assert(sizeof (size_t) == sizeof (mwSize));` and use any one of them. If the `assert` fails you're doomed.

Comment: @pmg: The assert will fail on a platform where `size_t` is larger than an `int` if you do not use the `-largeArrayDims` switch when compiling your mex function. That is the whole point of having the `mwSize` typedef.

Comment: +1 and thanks @Praetorian. As I said in the comment, the `assert` is meant as only a basic check: I don't know mex specific stuff.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mwSize` is defined for backward compatibility and portability. As the documentation states, it maps to an `int` when the `-largeArrayDims` switch is not used during compilation, and `size_t` when it is. So, in the first case `mwSize` is signed, but in the second, it isn't.

Using `mwSize` in your code allows you to re-use the code on all platforms, irrespective of whether that flag is used or not.

As for the API inconsistencies you've pointed out, they are truly inconsistencies, but not ones for major concern. `mxGetN()` will never return a negative number, so having it return a `size_t` is OK. However, (I'm guessing) older versions or versions of the mex API on certain platforms expect an int to passed to `mxCreateDoubleMatrix()` so defining the function as taking an input of type `mwSize` makes it portable and / or backward compatible.

Short answer is, use `mwSize` and use `-largeArrayDims` to compile the mex function.

Comment: Another question on style: mwIndex and mwSize are (in the documentation) identical, except that one is for the index and one is for the size. What is the reason for this? Is it just to make code clearer? So in `for(i=0; i<=n; i++)`, i would be mwIndex and n would be mwSize, but to me the division seems unneccessary.

Comment: @Har: I've never understood the reason for having mwIndex either. It does make the code easier to follow in some cases, but as you've pointed out, when iterating over some dimension of an mxArray you end up with an mwIndex compared to an mwSize and I don't like that either. I tend to use mwSize for everything.